# Delete nested hash according to key => value

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I have this hash:

```
response = '{"librairies":[{"id":1,"books":[{"id":1,"qty":1},{"id":2,"qty":3}]},{"id":2,"books":[{"id":1,"qty":0},{"id":2,"qty":3}]}]}'
```

in which I'd like to delete every librairies where, at least, one of the book quantity is null.

For instance, with this given `response`, I'd expect this return:

```
'{"librairies":[{"id":1,"books":[{"id":1,"qty":1},{"id":2,"qty":3}]}]}'
```

I've tried this:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(response)

parsed["librairies"].each do |library|
  library["books"].each do |book|
    parsed.delete(library) if book["qty"] == 0
  end
end
```

but this returns the exact same `response` hash, without having deleted the second library (the one with id => 2).

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: it means this code returns me the same hash.

Comment: The same hash as what?  I'm not going to assume that I know what you mean; you need to be precise in your descriptions.

Comment: Same, as in the same hash he started with before trying the delete.  In other words, his code is not changing anything, so he gets "the same hash" as he started with.

Comment: @geo one thing comes to mind after all this time. `0 != nil` in `ruby`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) and [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) for this

```
# Move through each array element with delete_if
parsed["librairies"].delete_if do |library|
  # evaluates to true if any book hash in the library
  # has a "qty" value of 0
  library["books"].any? { |book| book["qty"] == 0 }
end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To avoid changing the hash `parsed`, you could do the following.

Firstly, let's format `parsed` so we can see what we're dealing with:

```
parsed = { "libraries"=>[ { "id"=>1,
                            "books"=>[ { "id"=>1, "qty"=>1 },
                                       { "id"=>2, "qty"=>3 } ]
                          },
                          { "id"=>2,
                            "books"=>[ { "id"=>1, "qty"=>0 },
                                       { "id"=>2, "qty"=>3 } ]
                          }
                        ]
         }
```

Later I want to show that `parsed` has not been changed when we create the new hash. An easy way of doing that is to compute a hash code on `parsed` before and after, and see if it changes. (While it's not 100% certain that different hashes won't have the same hash code, here it's not something to lose sleep over.)

```
parsed.hash
  #=> 852445412783960729
```

We first need to make a "deep copy" of `parsed` so that changes to the copy will not affect `parsed`. One way of doing that is to use the [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Marshal.html) module:

```
new_parsed = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(parsed))
```

We can now modify the copy as required:

```
new_parsed["libraries"].reject! { |h| h["books"].any? { |g| g["qty"].zero? } }
  #=> [ { "id"=>1,
  #       "books"=>[ { "id"=>1, "qty"=>1 },
  #                  { "id"=>2, "qty"=>3 }
  #                ]
  #     }
  #   ]

new_parsed # => { "libraries"=>[ { "id"=>1,
                                   "books"=>[ { "id"=>1, "qty"=>1},
                                              { "id"=>2, "qty"=>3}
                                            ]
                                 }
                               ]
                }
```

And we confirm the original hash was not changed:

```
parsed.hash
  #=> 852445412783960729
```